# Can we display object values/collections in tabular format in visual studio debug visualizer?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, debuggervisualizer

Is it feasible to display the object values or collection of object values in tabular format similar to DataTable in visual studio debug visualizer? By writing a custom visualizer?
I feel this will give a quick glance of all values at once instead of expanding each item to see its values.

Is this technically achievable or are there any constraints that stops objects to be displayed in tabular view?

[image]

How I would like to see the above "Results View" is

[image]

I can understand it can be challenging if object/collection is too big but atleast this helps in majority of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that does this kind of job

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181451/Visual-Studio-Collection-Visualizers?msg=5383746

http://rapiddevbookcode.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EnumerableDebugVisualizer (Looks good but buggy with other tabbed features)

Comment: Since it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Thanks for your sharing:)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built into [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com), a commercial extension to Visual Studio I co-created.

[image: Video]

Here is [the basic premise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gg0hGWKOBoo)

And here is an [instructional video](http://o.oz-code.com/videos#97641391)